# How to delete target folder created using scp by target user

Tags: linux, scp, chmod

I have a machines `A` `B` `C`. only `Machine B` have access to `A` & `C`. For `machine A` I have root access , `machine B` I have root access and for `machine C` I have User level access.

1.2.3.4 is the ip address assigned to `machine B`.

When I am doing from `machine A` as
 `scp -pr ./logs/  root@1.2.3.4:/common/tftpboot/`
It creating folder name `logs` inside `<machine C>:/common/tftpboot/`
I have given all `read` `write` `execute` permission to all `user` `groups` and `others`  as `machine A` is comes under others using `chmod 777 tftpboot`

Now after copying `logs` folder I am not able to delete the `<machine C>:/common/tftpboot/logs/`folder from `User` of `machine C` though `machine C user` has given the 777 permission to `/common/tftpboot/` folder as the `logs` folder is created by others i.e `machine A root`

So I want to do scp to copy the folder only (and not individual files) and still I want that `user c` should able to delete the folder created by `machine A` `scp` after analysing logs

Now I need to  do ssh to `Machine B` from `Machine A` and then only I can able to delete the `scp` created logs folder.

can anybody help to do so ??

Comment: my head is spinning. what are the permissions of the files in the log folder?

Comment: @jgr208 It is sounds like vertigo.Anyway, for files under logs folder permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x` and for logs folder permissions are `drwxr-xr-x` and I am copying whole `logs` folder not only individual files inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before doing SCP I have changed permission of the logs folder to 777 i.e chmod -R 777 ./logs and now I can able to delete the folder created by scp at `Machine C`